# cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined cypress error

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

When I run this code, it gives error. I am not getting what am I doing wrong with this.

```
export class Login{
    enterEmail(){
        return cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(Cypress.env('USER_LOGIN_EMAIL'))
    }
    enterPassword(){
        return cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(Cypress.env('USER_LOGIN_PASSWORD'))
    }
    signInBtn(){
        return cy.get('button[data-cy="login_signin_button"]').click()
    }
}
```

Comment: Either `Cypress.env('USER_LOGIN_EMAIL')` or `Cypress.env('USER_LOGIN_PASSWORD')` is undefined, the reason is most likely a typo in your .env file

Answer (score 0):

As ChrisG said, one of either `Cypress.env('USER_LOGIN_EMAIL')` or `Cypress.env('USER_LOGIN_PASSWORD')` is undefined. You can define environment variables in multiple ways, but I would suggest, if these values are going to be static, to define them [in your configuration.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-1-configuration-file)

Answer (score 0):

how are you? There are a some points we need to check, to understand why you are getting undefined.

First we need to understand where those environment variables are saved, they could be saved in a `cypress.env.json` file or in another `.env` file.

If they are saved in a `cypress.env.json` file, check if this file is in a JSON format like bellow with the correct variable names:

```
{
   "USER_LOGIN_EMAIL": "some.email@gmail.com",
   "USER_LOGIN_PASSWORD": "some.password"
}
```

If they aren't in a `cypress.env.json` but they are in another `.env` file, your environment variables in this other file should have a prefix `CYPRESS_` so their correct names should be:

```
CYPRESS_USER_LOGIN_EMAIL
CYPRESS_USER_LOGIN_PASSWORD
```

If your environment variables don't exist in any `.env` file you can create the `cypress.env.json` like above or you can manually export in the terminal before running Cypress each time you open a new terminal using:

```
export CYPRESS_USER_LOGIN_EMAIL=some.email@gmail.com
export CYPRESS_USER_LOGIN_PASSWORD=some.password
```